# HTML within link_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, erb

I'm pretty new to Rails templates.

Here's my current code:

```
<li><%= link_to "Home", "/path1" %></li>
```

Here's how I'd like the code to work:

```
          <li><a href="path1"><i class="icon-home icon-white icon-active"></i> Home</a></li>
```

I have tried with no avail to figure this out. Basically I just want an embedded  tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can pass a block to link_to:

```
<li>
<%= link_to "/path1" do %>
  <i class="icon-home icon-white icon-active"></i> Home</a>
<% end %>
</li>
```